# Convert 8 bit signed integer to unsigned and then convert to int32

Tags: c, integer

I have a signed 8-bit integer (`int8_t`) -- which can be any value from `-5` to `5` -- and need to convert it to an unsigned 8-bit integer (`uint8_t`).

This `uint8_t` value then gets passed to another piece of hardware (which can only handle 32-bit types) and needs to be converted to a `int32_t`.

How can I do this?

Example code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

void main() {

    int8_t input;
    uint8_t package;
    int32_t output;

    input = -5;
    package = (uint8_t)input;
    output = (int32_t)package;

    printf("output = %d",output);
}
```

In this example, I start with `-5`. It temporarily gets cast to `251` so it can be packaged as a `uint8_t`. This data then gets sent to another piece of hardware where I can't use `(int8_t)` to cast the 8-bit unsigned integer back to signed before casting to `int32_t`. Ultimately, I want to be able to obtain the original `-5` value.

For more info, the receiving hardware is a SHARC processor which doesn't allow `int8_t` - see https://ez.analog.com/dsp/sharc-processors/f/q-a/118470/error-using-stdint-h-types

> The smallest addressable memory unit on the SHARC processor is 32 bits, which means that the minimum size of any data type is 32 bits. This applies to the native C types like char and short. Because the types "int8_t", "uint16_t" specify that the size of the type *must* be 8 bits and 16 bits respectively, they cannot be supported for SHARC.

Comment: It really depends on what you mean by "convert". What do you expect `-5` to become when you convert it from `int8_t` to `uint8_t`? In your current code, it becomes `251`.

Comment: The real question here is, why do you need to pass through `uint8_t` first? Because you want to keep an unsigned 8 bit value and then extend it to 32 bits?

Comment: Thanks for your comment - it's to do with hardware restrictions. I'm sending data from one piece of hardware to another. All data needs to be send in unsigned integer 8 bit packages. But the hardware I'm receiving on doesn't allow me to cast to (int8_t) before casting to int32_t

Comment: You will have to clarify what you want your final result to be with a few examples, we can't just guess what you want to do. Do you want the `-5` to keep being `-5` when it is finally converted to `int32_t`?

Comment: yes I do want it to keep being `-5`. I'll add some more details to my post.

Comment: It seems that your requirements are muddy. Hardware does usually not need signed numbers. What is the actual problem you are trying to solve? Are you trying to invent a data communication protocol? Signedness and endianess etc then need to be specified for that protocol and every CPU making use of it has to convert to/from that protocol.

Comment: If the destination hardware doesn't support data in units smaller than 32 bits, then how does it make sense to send data to it "in unsigned integer 8 bit packages"?  You are probably approaching this from the wrong angle.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Probably, the value is read from a 32-bit register, but with bits 31-8 all zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one possible branch-free conversion:

```
output = package; // range 0 to 255
output -= (output & 0x80) << 1;
```

The second line will subtract 256 if bit 7 is set, e.g.:

- 251 has bit 7 set, 251 - 256 = -5
- 5 has bit 7 clear, 5 - 0 = 5

Comment: I would rather check the sign extension instruction and use it is as intrinsic. Those processors are programmed the most **efficient** way, ignoring the portability.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the negative sign back using 32-bit operations, you could do something like this:

```
   output = (int32_t)package;
   if (output & 0x80) { /* char sign bit set */
        output |= 0xffffff00;
   }

   printf("output = %d",output);
```

Answer (score 1):

Since your receiver platform does not have types that are less than 32 bits wide, your simplest option is to solve this problem on the sender:

```c
int8_t input = -5;
int32_t input_extended = input;
uint8_t buffer[4];

memcpy(buffer, &input_extended, 4);

send_data(buffer, 4);
```

Then on the receiving end you can simply treat the data as a single `int32_t`:

```c
int32_t received_data;

receive_data(&received_data, 4);
```

All of this is assuming that your sender and receiver share the same [endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness). If not, you will have to flip the endianness in the sender before sending:

```c
int8_t input = -5;
int32_t input_extended = input;
uint32_t tmp = (uint32_t)input_extended;

tmp = ((tmp >> 24) & 0x000000ff)
    | ((tmp >>  8) & 0x0000ff00)
    | ((tmp <<  8) & 0x00ff0000)
    | ((tmp << 24) & 0xff000000);

uint8_t buffer[4];

memcpy(buffer, &tmp, 4);

send_data(buffer, 4);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just **subtract 256 from the value**, because in [2's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) an n-bit negative value ***v*** is stored as ***2<sup>n</sup> - v***

```
input = -5;
package = (uint8_t)input;
output = package > 127 ? (int32_t)package - 256 : package;
```

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:**

If the issue is that your code has `if` statements for values of `-5` to `5`, than the simplest solution might be to test for `result + 5` and change the `if` statements to values between `0` and `10`.

This is probably what the compiler will do when optimizing (since values of 0-10 can be converted to a map, avoiding `if` statements and minimizing predictive CPU flushing).

---

Original:

Type casting will work if first cast to `uint8_t` and then `uint32_t`...

```
output = (int32_t)(uint32_t)(uint8_t)input;
```

Of course, if the 8th bit is set it will remain set, but the sign won't be extended since the type casting operation is telling the compiler to treat the 8th bit as a regular bit (it is unsigned).

Of course, you can always have fun with bit masking if you want to be even more strict, but that's essentially a waste or CPU cycles.

The code:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void main() {

  int8_t input;
  int32_t output;

  input = -5;
  output = (int32_t)(uint32_t)(uint8_t)input;

  printf("output = %d\n", output);
}
```

Results in "`output = 251`".